# How can i modify theme default @shoutem/theme

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I create new project react native, then i installed @shoutem/ui , @shoutem/theme, @shoutem/animation to my project via nom install...!
But i have problem when try to find some way better to modify global theme shoutem.
I found theme.js inside folder node_module/shoutem/ui like picture below here!
[image]

So best way to modify all them of app is modify this theme.js file?
when i try to modify 1 content like View, Image follow tutorial at here:
https://github.com/shoutem/theme
my navigation bar got error like this picture:
[image]

So can u guys help me, suggest me best way to modify global theme default of shoutem?
Do modify theme.js or using something else?

And one more thing! When i try to builder app via https://builder.shoutem.com/ then pull-app using terminal!
I got project! But don't see anything code inside, only extension and so much info! Do not know what is true code when builder complete!
here is picture project when pull-app done!
[image]

And here is index file:
[image]

So how can i learn form that if only sort info inside index.js file :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you should edit is in:

extensions/ExtensionName/app/theme/ThemeName.js

Where "ExtensionName" refers to the extension that has Screens which you are using in your app.

You should go through the Shoutem documentation on [how to write a Theme](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/writing-a-theme).

It will show you:

- how to create that file (ThemeName.js, your custom Theme)
- how you can customize it
- how you can use the Builder to manage details about it in Styles>Themes>Customize Theme
- how you can add more details for the Builder to manage

When you initially create a Theme as the aforementioned documentation explains, it'll be a copy of the default Shoutem theme, so you'll have a fully functioning Theme right out the box, which you can edit to suit your wants and needs.

You can also check out the Shoutem documentation about the [UI Toolkit](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/introduction) to find out more info about Shoutem Components (including [NavigationBar](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/components/navigation-bar)), [Themes](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/theme/introduction) and [Animations](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/animation/introduction).

The reason I'm linking all this documentation is because the documentation covers all of the issues displayed here in a way that's much more detailed than I could provide in an answer here and the misconceptions and misunderstandings of the questioner can be resolved by self-education.

Edit as response to comment:

You have to use:

```
$ npm install --save @shoutem/theme
```

Inside your project directory.

You can follow read [this](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/theme/introduction) documentation about Themes to better understand how to apply Theme styles to your own components.

If you want to edit specific components globally, you have to edit that component in:

node_modules/@shoutem/ui/components

Editing a file there will edit every iteration of the component throughout the app.

Comment: I feel my english skill to bad!
Cant tell you what i want :(
So i try to show you what i do and what i want again, hope you can know my mind!
I try create new project react native via this code:
$ react-native init HelloWorld
$ cd HelloWorld
then i install @shoutem/ui using:
$ react-native install @shoutem/ui
$ react-native link
when done, i got project and node_module have shoutem.
when i try to add component of shoutem, i got default theme, how to modify this in my project! i don't want create project like restaurants...